# Pass values to model from controller

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I need to create a table that is filled with data via ajax with the codes below:

**VIEW:**

```
<form class="form-inline" id="form_filter" method="POST">
                            <label for="date_from">From </label>
                            <input type="date" name="date_from">

                            <label for="date_to">&nbsp;&nbsp;To </label>
                            <input type="date" name="date_to">

                            <input type="button" name="btn_view_records" value="Filter Date" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="btn_view_records">
                        </form>

$('#btn_view_records').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data:$('#form_filter').serialize(),
            datataype:"JSON",
            url:"<?php echo site_url('pakyaw/get_filtered_data');?>",
            success:function(data){
                $("#log-list").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public function get_filtered_data(){
        $this->load->library('table');

        $this->table->set_heading('Bio Id', 'Log Date', 'Time In', 'Time Out', 'Time Rendendered');
        $style = array('table_open'  => '<table class="table table-striped table-hover">');
        $this->table->set_template($style);
        echo $this->table->generate($this->model_pakyaw->get_filtered_data($this->session->userdata('branch_name'), $this->input->post('date_from'), $this->input->post('date_to')));
    }
```

**MODEL:**

```
public function get_filtered_data($branch_name, $date_from, $date_to){
        $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);

        $str2="select bio_id as 'bio_id', cast(attendance as date) as 'Log Date', min(attendance) as 'time_in', max(attendance) as 'time_out', timediff(max(attendance), min(attendance)) as 'difference'  
            FROM delwater_downydb.pakyaw_attendance
            WHERE attendance > '".$date_from."'
            GROUP BY bio_id, cast(attendance as date)
            ORDER BY bio_id, cast(attendance as date) desc;";
        $query=$this->db->query($str2);
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

When I click the btn_view_records it doesn't filter the results. I checked and I have seen that the date_from is not being passed. The sql syntax is getting '' value that's why it is not filtering properly. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: the code look nothing wrong. can you show `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: How do I implement that? Sorry, basically new to PHP..

Comment: when I do this " print_r($_POST);die();"   It's just this..... "Array ( )"

Comment: that mean your form not post data to correct URL. check back your post URL.

Answer (score 0):

Typo in your ajax call?

`datataype:"JSON",` should be `dataType:"JSON",`

Answer (score 0):

pass variables assigned to post values or try to print POST values in the model.

```
print_r($_POST); //in model

$from_date  = $this->input->post('date_from');//in model
$date_to= $this->input->post('date_to');//in model

$result = $this->table->generate($this->model_pakyaw->get_filtered_data( $from_date, $date_to, $any_other_variable );// in controller

print_r($result);// in controller
```